# .net Core App 1.1 doesn't resolve external .net standard libs as file reference

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard, .net-core-1.1

I created a solution with 2 projects a .net core 1.1 host (console) and a .net standard 1.6 class library.

I add the reference as project refrence.

Then at runtime i get the exception that the assembly of the client is not found.
And this at the first place i use a type of the .net standard assembly
so my test console looks as trivial as this:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Class1();
```

When I switch the host project to .net core 1.0 everything is working fine.

I published a sample here: https://github.com/Gentlehag/coreapp11bug

Is this expected behavior ?

Which .net standard library version should work with .net core 1.1 ?

In the meanwhile a discussion is here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10037

Comment: Ps It seems to run when using Console Commands without vs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

.net core doesn't support file reference at all at this moment. although the ide allowes it...

> he .NET Core SDK v1.0 (Visual Studio 2017 RTM) doesn't support direct
>   references to assemblies on disk. Basically the options that will give
>   you success are either  or .
>
> We did enable this scenario for 2.0 though. See dotnet/sdk#120, but
>   those bits have not been released yet. They will be when .NET Core 2.0
>   comes out later this year.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4772#issuecomment-285394790

So the solution is to wrap up in nuget packages or create a solution which adds all existing projects

Comment: How would I deal with a 3rd-party assembly? I have a COM interop dll (from [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm)) that I'm trying to use in a .NET Core 1.1 project and I am at a loss.